# C#. Обработка нажатия inline и reply кнопок для бота telegram

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Для создания telegram-бота использую package Telegram.Bot.13.4.0.
Сделал inline-кнопки следующим образом:

```
var keyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
{
    new [] // first row
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("1.1","www.google.com"),
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.2"),
    },
    new [] // second row
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.1"),
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.2"),
    }
});
await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Жамкни!", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

Подскажите, как теперь обработать событие нажатия на эти кнопки?
К примеру, я в telegram нажимаю на inline-кнопку, а бот должен мне прислать ответ.

Также интересует, как обработать событие нажатия на reply-кнопку. Их делаю следующим образом:

```
var keyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.ReplyKeyboardMarkup
{
    Keyboard = new[] {
    new[] // row 1
    {
        new Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton("Первая кнопко"),
        new Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton("Вторая кнопко"),
    },
},
    ResizeKeyboard = true
};
await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Жамкни!", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButton[][] 
                                        {new [] {
                                                 new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButton("Текст для первой кнопки","callback1"),                                                                
                                                 new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButton("Текст второй кнопки","callback2"),
                                                 },
                                       });
```

Вот код создания кнопок. Потом тебе нужно подписаться на событие `Bot.OnCallbackQuery`. И там обрабатывать нажатие на кнопки.

```
Bot.OnCallbackQuery += async (object sc, Telegram.Bot.Args.CallbackQueryEventArgs ev) =>
            {
                var message = ev.CallbackQuery.Message;
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback1")
                {
                   // сюда то что тебе нужно сделать при нажатии на первую кнопку 
                }
                else
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback2")
                {
                    // сюда то что нужно сделать при нажатии на вторую кнопку
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

*Reply*-кнопки отправляют в чат сообщение с текстом загловка - "*Первая кнопко*", например. Обрабатывайте это так же как и любой другой текст, отправленный пользователем.

С *инлайн*-кнопками по-другому, они в чат ничего не отправляют, но посылают боту коллбэк, который и служит маркером того, какая именно кнопка была нажата. Помимо подписки на события, как предложил @*Be Happy*, можно работать простым `switch-case`, например:

```
        switch (update.Type)
        {
            case UpdateType.MessageUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.CallbackQueryUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.PreCheckoutQueryUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.ShippingQueryUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.InlineQueryUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.ChosenInlineResultUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.EditedMessage:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.ChannelPost:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.EditedChannelPost:
                //...
                break;
            case UpdateType.UnknownUpdate:
                //...
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Прекрасно делается через `switch`:

```
switch (update.Type)
   {
      case UpdateType.CallbackQuery:
          chatId = update.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id;
          var pressedButtonID = update.CallbackQuery.Data; // Сюда вытягиваешь callbackData из кнопки.
          Console.WriteLine($"Pressed button = {pressedButtonID}"); 
          break;
      default:
          break;
   }
```

Comment: Оставляйте, пожалуйста, чуть более развернутые ответы. В данном случае автор вопроса возможно и не знает вообще что update бывает разных типов, etc...

Comment: Я самое нужное выделил, только тот тип куда и приходит апдейт по нажатой кнопке